# Use Prometheus in .netFramework 4.5 application to get HTTP statuses

Tags: .net, prometheus

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        app.UsePrometheusServer(q =>
        {
            q.MapPath = "/test-metrics";
        });

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

I'm `using Prometheus.Client.Owin;`, this works fine, but it produces very little metrics. I need to get some metrics on HTTP statuses/durations on my endpoints in .NET 452 wep app.

```
Metrics.CreateCounter("newCounter", "some help about this");
```

Is there a better way than adding just a simple counter everywhere in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion:
Add a class fx called MetricsMiddleware:

```
using HttpContext = System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>;
using RequestDelegate = Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, Task>;
public class MetricsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public MetricsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext raw)
    {
        var context = raw.Wrapped();
        var path = context.Request.Path.Value;
        var method = context.Request.Method;
        var counter = Metrics.CreateCounter("aspnet_request_total", "HTTP Requests Total",
            new CounterConfiguration
            {
                LabelNames = new[] { "path", "method", "status" }
            });
        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(raw);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            counter.Labels(path, method, "500").Inc();
            throw;
        }
        counter.Labels(path, method, context.Response.StatusCode.ToString()).Inc();
    }
}
```

And a static class fx called IMyAppBuilderExtensions:

```
public static class IMyAppBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void EnableRequestMetrics(this IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<MetricsMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

And then add it to your Configuration method before app.UseWebApi():

```
app.EnableRequestMetrics();
```

That did the trick for me. You can customize the Invoke method to include durations.